# jasmine-jquery toBeDisabled not working

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have got following html

```
<a disabled="disabled"><img alt="First" src="/Content/Images/Grid/disabledFirst.png"></a>
```

And I run following `expect` on this html

```
expect($(element)).toBeDisabled()
```

where `element` is the selector for above html. The `expect` fails. Further investigation lead to following code in jasmine-jquery-1.3.1.js

```
toBeDisabled: function(selector){
      return this.actual.is(':disabled');
    },
```

which for some reason is returning false. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here but just not able to spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XE6aq/) shows that jQuery only finds inputs not anchors when using `:disabled`. It's understandable because the [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/HTMLAnchorElement#Properties) doesn't have the `disabled` property